# Programmatically Make a SKLabelNode Bold in swift

Tags: swift, fonts, sklabelnode

As the title states - I would like to make my `SKLabelNode`bold programmatically.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For SKLabelNode's you need to use:

```
var labelNode = SKLabelNode()
labelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Bold")
```

or

```
var labelNode = SKLabelNode()
labelNode.fontName = "AvenirNext-Bold"
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `SKLabelNode.init(attributedText:)` with and`NSAttributedString`

Answer (score 4):

You can't set the SKLabelNode itself to bold. You have to use a Bold Font.

But if you want to use a custom font, you have to use one which is available in bold:

```
skLabel.fontName = "YourFontName-Bold"
skLabel.fontSize = 14
```

To get all fonts which are available on iOS check this site: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: For some reason the .Font isn't recognised though - SKLabelNode doesn't have a member named Font

Comment: you have to write the .font with a lowercase 'f'.

Comment: tried both and still get not a member (even with .font)

Comment: Ah i see. you are using an SKLabelnode. I thought that you were using an UILAbel. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That did it! Perfect!  Thanks Guys - What is the default font of the LabelNode?

I don't want to choose a new font and i don't know the name of the default one

Comment: You can get the Fontname by simply print it out: println(skLabel.fontName). If my answer solved your problem please click on the tick on the left side of my answer so that other people can find it easier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little extension for SKLabelNode. Allows you to toggle between bold and non-bold. Return value tells if it is currently set to bold.

```
extension SKLabelNode
{
    func toggleBold() -> Bool
    {
        if var range = self.fontName.rangeOfString("-Bold")
        {
            self.fontName = self.fontName.substringToIndex(range.startIndex)
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            self.fontName = self.fontName + "-Bold"
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use font property of UILabel

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
```

or use default system font to bold text

```
lable.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16.0)
```

Comment: Question was regarding `SKLabelNode`, not `UILabel`.